# How to convert hdf4 to hdf5 in python by using h4toh5?

Tags: python, hdf5, hdf

I want to convert hdf4 file to hdf5 in python, and I think this tool `h4toh5` could be used to solve this problem, but I have no idea how to use it in python, anyone knows?

Tool available at https://www.hdfgroup.org/h4toh5/

Comment: It doesn't look like a python library. It looks like it could be for C/C++ programs

Comment: Thanks! Is there any tool for python to convert hdf4 to hdf5?

Comment: http://hdfeos.org/software/pyhdf.php

Comment: You should take a look at this answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/141930

Comment: Yes I know pyhdf could read hdf4, but I'm writing a class in a big programme whose `read hdf` class uses h5py, and I cannot change it, so what I can do is to change hdf4 file to hdf5 in my own class.

Comment: Updated URL to h4toh5 tools: https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/h4toh5/

Comment: You should be able to use `pyhdf` to open and handle HDF4 files.

Answer (score 1):

You can download h4toh5 from https://www.hdfeos.org/software/h4toh5-def-download.php

Then you can run the binary using subprocess

```
import subprocess
args = ("./h4toh5", filepath)
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```